# XPath select a link set in JavaScript

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to retrieve a link using XPath. The link is for a pagination and is set in JavaScript. The website is stocklot.com.
using this code :

```
$x("//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href")
```

I'm able to get this:

```
[href="javascript:setPaginazione('FRM_ADS','http://www.stocklot.com/home/list/0/30/30.html');”]
```

Do you know how I can select just the link without the JavaScript part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution assumes that the string - like the value of the href attribute in the question -  ends with the 3 characters `');`.
For the simplified example

```
<root>
  <div class="pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone">
    <ul>
        <li>
           first
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:setPaginazione('FRM_ADS','http://www.stocklot.com/home/list/0/30/30.html');">link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</root>
```

the XPath

```
string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href)
```

returns

```
javascript:setPaginazione('FRM_ADS','http://www.stocklot.com/home/list/0/30/30.html');
```

To get only the link, the XPath can be adjusted to:

```
substring(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),string-length(substring-before(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),'http')) + 1,string-length(substring-after(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),'http')) + 1)
```

Result:

```
http://www.stocklot.com/home/list/0/30/30.html
```

For readability above XPath indented and just as example the string retrieved with `string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href)` written as `$string` :

```
substring($string, string-length(substring-before($string,'http'))+ 1,
          string-length(substring-after($string,'http')) + 1)
```

As additional note:

```
substring(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),string-length(substring-before(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),'http')) + 1)
```

results in

```
http://www.stocklot.com/home/list/0/30/30.html');
```

Though it would be possible to get the position of `.html` and use a similar XPath to `substring()` after `.html`, it's possible that the link could end in `.php` or contain parameters (like e.g. ending in `.html?id=10`), so above approach just cuts off the last 3 characters.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. Sorry but i'm no expert.... if i put this in the console: substring(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),string-length(substring-before(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),'http')) + 1)
it return an error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } hope you can help me! thanks again!

Comment: @Marco No problem, I've just checked and your XPath is not complete :) It's like in the answer `substring(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),string-length(substring-before(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),'http')) + 1,string-length(substring-after(string(//div[@class='pagination pagination-centered hidden-phone']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href),'http')) + 1`  , I've checked again here: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and it returns the result at least for the example input.

Comment: @Marco Glad I was able to help you. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as solved/closed. In case you don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235